# Azure Functions Core tools suddenly stopped working

Tags: azure, .net-core

I was in the middle of working on some minor code changes when all of a sudden I started getting the following error on startup:

```
 A host error has occurred during startup operation '78d5d8fd-e81c-4707-87ca-6b801430fef1'.
[2021-01-08T13:02:40.279Z] System.IO.FileSystem: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\schiefaw\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\3.17.0\workers'.
```

I looked at the path and found everything exists until I get to "workers".

I, of course, assumed it was something I did, so I backed out all changes to no effect. Then I uninstalled visual studio and all Azure products I could find and reinstalled to no effect. I created a new user (since the file it is looking for is in my user folder) to no effect.

I then created an entirely new instance of a windows virtual machine and installed the development environment to no effect (same error).

I am completely stuck on this. Does anyone have any ideas on what I can try next?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is a bug from that 3.17 release. But here is a work-around: you can add the "workers" folder (empty folder) and it should work. Another way if you have a copy of the previous version (such as 3.16.x), you can copy the content to the 3.17.0 one.

You can read more here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1304718/azure-functions-local-debugging-broke-with-3170-up.html

Comment: OMG! Thank you! I was up all night beating against that wall and today a bunch of other stuff is going on and I am too foggy to think straight. You saved me! I am up and running again.